# Do I need to watch any Godzilla movie before 2016 Shin Godzilla?

Tags: godzilla

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_Godzilla) called 2016 Shin Godzilla a "reboot".

Does that mean I won't lose anything by not watching any previous Japanese Godzilla movies? (in terms of universe/continuity knowledge beneficial to watching the new film)?

Comment: You need to watch *every* Godzilla movie before 2016 Shin Godzilla. Get going!

Comment: You may have to learn Japanese though unless it is finally available in a SUBed or DUBed version.

Comment: @ShadoCat - good point. I assumed there was English version from a huge # of Wikipedia-cited reviews from US sources.

Comment: @ShadoCat - https://screenrant.com/shin-godzilla-home-release-blu-ray-details/

Comment: Shin Godzilla - is he shorter than a usual Godzilla because Americans shot his legs, and he had to be put together without shins? If so, Cotton Hill was probably behind it....

Comment: Nobody needs to watch any Godzilla or any other movie.  But watching movies is often a lot of fun.  Of course you asked if you need to watch earlier Godzilla movies for reasons of plot and background of 2016 Shin Godzilla.  I would certainly recommend watching the first Godzilla film, preferably the original Japanese version subbed or dubbed.  Even if it is totally retconned and not plot relevant to 2016 Shin Godzilla it would be worth watching anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Wikia [also calls this a reboot](http://godzilla.wikia.com/wiki/Shin_Godzilla)

> Shin Godzilla was co-directed by Hideaki Anno and Shinji Higuchi, with a screenplay written by Anno. The film acts as a reboot to the series, and details Godzilla's origins, and his arrival in Japan for the first time, while also showcasing the human response to the disaster.

Since the plot goes on to detail Godzilla's origins, it's clearly cutting continuity with the previous films. It's worth noting that canon in the previous films has been [spotty at best](http://www.tohokingdom.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10919) (i.e. [Hedorah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Hedorah) no longer exists), so it's simpler to make a clean reboot so future films are not burdened.

Answer (score 0):

It's a clean reboot. You don't need to know anything about previous Godzilla films, any of the characters, any of the events, or anything else of the mythology. You might get a bit more out of it on the meta level with references and the odd in-joke, but nothing in the actual film requires prior knowledge.

Comment: What is the source for this? What are the references/in-jokes?

Comment: Among others, one of the jokes is that the Prime Minister meets with three older scientists to get their advice. In the three of the original films, the Prime Minister met with a scientist at the start and received useful information/advice. In the new film, they're utterly useless. Also, some of the sound effects are taken from older films.